# Loopback related model on existing database?

Tags: loopbackjs

I've currently built an API using `Loopback` based on an existing DB and schema from an older API. Everything works very well with the exception of 'populate' or `related models`.

I would like to be able to query related models in the loopback way, like so

```
User.find({include: 'test'}, function() { /* ... */ });
```

i've added the relations in the JSON files

```
"relations": {
    "test": {
        "type": "hasOne",
        "model": "Address",
        "foreignKey": "addressId"
    }
}
```

however I can't seem to get anything to be returned - although I can see the additional properties in the explorer.

So, my question is, can related models be set-up over existing data or does it have to be populated as the data is created?

EDIT: my connector is mongo

Comment: It can be set up with the existing data. What's the schema of the tables? Also in your example, your relation name is `test`, so you have to `include` with that name: `User.find({ include: 'test' })`

Comment: For more debugging you can see the loopback queries, if you set the `DEBUG` environment variable with `loopback:*`

Comment: Thanks @FaridNouriNeshat an oversight pasting code, have updated the ticket. Regarding setting up with existing data is there a link you know of? I've edited the question to state i'm using the mongo connector.

Comment: You can use [`instance introspection`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Creating-models-from-unstructured-data.html) to create the models but it won't have the relationships set up. Can you share valid examples of data from both collections?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat thank you for your help. Turns out it was quite simple after all and i just didn't understand how to set-up the foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on another SO quesiton: [Loopback-relationship-on-non-id-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802071/loopback-relationship-on-non-id-field)

It turns out the `foreignKey` needs to be the same for `hasMany` and `belongsTo`